# $\sigma$-algebra generated by a set

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I want to show that if $X$ is an uncountable set then $\mathcal{S}=\{\{x\}:x\in X\}$ generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}=\{A\subset X: A$ is countable or $X\setminus A$ is uncountable$\}$.

I proceed as follows:

Clearly $\mathcal{S}\subset \mathcal{A}$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{S}$. Then it can be shown that $\mathcal{B}\supset \mathcal{A}$. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma-algebra to conclude that $\mathcal{S}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ implies that $\sigma(\mathcal{S})\subseteq\mathcal{A}$.

To show that $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{S})$ you take an $A\in\mathcal{A}$ and split into two cases: 1) $A$ is countable and 2) $X\setminus A$ is countable. Then it should be pretty straightforward to write $A$ as something belonging to $\sigma(\mathcal{S})$.